# Debian 'bullseye' - 'apt full-upgrade' removes whole lot of packages

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I just run `apt full-upgrade` on my system:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
          Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-1-686-pae
    Architecture: x86
```

and it removed a whole lot of applications/packages:

```
Entfernen von doconce (0.7.3-1) ...
Entfernen von gladish (1+dfsg0-6) ...
Entfernen von gtklick (0.6.4-5) ...
Entfernen von jack-mixer (10-1+b1) ...
Entfernen von ladish (1+dfsg0-6) ...
Entfernen von laditools (1.1.0-3.1) ...
Entfernen von python-dev (2.7.17-2) ...
Entfernen von libpython-dev:i386 (2.7.17-2) ...
Entfernen von tinyeartrainer (0.1.0-4) ...
Entfernen von uzbl (0.0.0~git.20120514-1.2) ...
Entfernen von python-support (1.0.15) ...
Entfernen von termsaver (0.3-1) ...
Entfernen von mididings (0~20120419~ds0-6) ...
Entfernen von preprocess (1.1.0+ds-1) ...
Entfernen von pyrit (0.5.1+git20180801-2) ...
Entfernen von python-pytest (4.6.9-2) ...
Entfernen von python-atomicwrites (1.1.5-2) ...
Entfernen von python-matplotlib (2.2.4-4) ...
Entfernen von python-bs4 (4.8.2-1) ...
Entfernen von python-soupsieve (1.9.5+dfsg-1) ...
Entfernen von python-backports.functools-lru-cache (1.5-3) ...
Entfernen von python-colorama (0.3.7-1) ...
Entfernen von python-openssl (19.0.0-1) ...
Entfernen von python-cryptography (2.8-3+b1) ...
Entfernen von python-statsmodels (0.9.0-6) ...
Entfernen von python-pandas (0.23.3+dfsg-8) ...
Entfernen von python-dateutil (2.7.3-3) ...
Entfernen von python-sip (4.19.21+dfsg-1) ...
Entfernen von python-laditools (1.1.0-3.1) ...
Entfernen von python-enum34 (1.1.6-2) ...
Entfernen von python-fpconst (0.7.2-6) ...
Entfernen von python-mock (3.0.5-1) ...
Entfernen von python-funcsigs (1.0.2-4) ...
Entfernen von python-lz4 (2.1.10+dfsg-1+b1) ...
Entfernen von python-future (0.18.2-1) ...
Entfernen von python-glade2 (2.24.0-6) ...
Entfernen von python-gtk2 (2.24.0-6) ...
Entfernen von python-html5lib (1.0.1-2) ...
Entfernen von python-pluggy (0.13.0-2) ...
Entfernen von python-importlib-metadata (1.5.0-1) ...
Entfernen von python-uritools (2.2.0-1) ...
Entfernen von python-ipaddress (1.0.17-1) ...
Entfernen von python-ly (0.9.5-2) ...
Entfernen von python-mako (1.0.7+ds1-1) ...
Entfernen von python-mididings (0~20120419~ds0-6+b1) ...
Entfernen von python-zipp (1.0.0-1) ...
Entfernen von python-more-itertools (4.2.0-1) ...
Entfernen von python-parse (1.6.6-0.1) ...
Entfernen von python-pathlib2 (2.3.5-1) ...
Entfernen von python-patsy (0.5.0+git13-g54dcf7b-1) ...
Entfernen von python-pyinotify (0.9.6-1.2) ...
Entfernen von python-scandir (1.10.0-2) ...
Entfernen von python-scapy (2.4.3-3) ...
Entfernen von python-selenium (3.14.1+dfsg1-1) ...
Entfernen von python-statsmodels-lib:i386 (0.9.0-6) ...
Entfernen von python-subprocess32 (3.5.4-1) ...
Entfernen von python-webencodings (0.5.1-1) ...
Entfernen von python-xlwt (1.3.0-2) ...
Entfernen von speedpad (1.0-2) ...
Entfernen von python (2.7.17-2) ...
Entfernen von libpython-stdlib:i386 (2.7.17-2) ...
Entfernen von python-minimal (2.7.17-2) ...
```

other packages like `proxychains` for an example do not work anymore, due to missing `python` packages:

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
/usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory
```

**are all those packages obsolete and I have to search and install them manually now?**

Answer (score 3):

This is part of [the Python 2 clean-up in Debian 11](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/2Removal). The original plan was to remove Python 2 entirely, but that changed recently to [removing the unversioned Python packages](https://lists.debian.org/debian-python/2019/07/msg00080.html) and [keeping some Python 2 packages](https://lists.debian.org/debian-python/2020/07/msg00039.html). The unversioned package removal was done in [`python-defaults` 2.7.18-1](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1164934/accepted-python-defaults-2718-1-source-into-unstable/), followed by 2.7.18-2, which [migrated to Debian 11 yesterday](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1176103/python-defaults-2718-2-migrated-to-testing/).

As a result, your `full-upgrade` removed the default Python packages and all the obsolete packages which still depended on them. Note that these had already been removed from Debian 11, in some cases long ago; [`doconce` for example nearly a year ago](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/doconce).

If you still need Python 2-based software you should stick with Debian 10.

Comment: "If you still need Python 2-based software you should stick with Debian 10." That does not really make me happy, honestly... :-(((

Answer (score 1):

Something looks very suspicious with the version `2.7.17-2` of the `python` package in Debian unstable. The last upgrade I did also attempted to remove a lot of Python packages because they were not referenced by any manually installed package. It looks like a bad configuration of the `python` package.

For example, attempting to install `python` again on my machine shows the following message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.17-2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.17-2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: python2 (= 2.7.17-2) but 2.7.18-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For the moment, you can [re]install the `python2` and `python3` packages so that `apt` marks them as manually installed, in order to keep the dependent packages installed even when `apt autoremove` is invoked.

This is clearly a bug that needs to be fixed. It's a bummer that it happened while you were running `full-upgrade`. Consider switching to Debian stable if you don't mind out-of-date software.

Comment: **I think this is worse than a "bummer"!** It made whole parts of my system completely useless :-(

Answer (score 0):

**This answer does not solve the problem of all the packages that got automatically removed by** `apt full-upgrade`

but it solves the second part of the question:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory
```

This is due to a missing symlink, the system does not find `python3`.
If Python3 has been installed, run this command to find its location: `whereis python3`

This prints something like:

```
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3.8-coverage /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3.9 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3.4 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.9 /usr/include/python3.8m /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Then you can create a symlink to it, by running: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

**This fixed it to me.**
[Thanks to this answer on Ask-Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235537)