# Cannot complete upgrade of Debian Buster to Bullseye

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, upgrade

So, it has been 17 months since Buster release (and setting Bullseye as testing) and I still cannot complete the Buster to Bullseye upgrade. It's not the first time I am upgrading Debian, but this time it overwhelmed me.

My first try happened in summer this year, but I surrendered. I managed to upgrade some of the packages, but most of them (over a thousand) remained not upgraded. You can see my earlier "findings" here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596078/447111

I tried today, but failed again. Currently `# apt-get dist-upgrade` results in: *1013 upgraded, 380 newly installed, 129 to remove, 8 not upgraded*. The 129 packages to be removed include **kde-runtime** (and some other KDE-related), nvidia-driver (and related), python and a lot of lib packages, which is unacceptable.

I have searched the web again and the problem seems to be quite common, yet there are no official fixes or workarounds. Some people say *remove gcc-8* (https://prodevsblog.com/questions/690521/full-upgrade-to-debian-testing-fails-due-to-libc6-dev-breaks-libgcc-8-dev/), others say *install gcc-8-base* (https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/h878ci/fullupgrade_to_debian_testing_fails_due_to/) etc., but none worked for me. One guy says that the problem is related to **gcc-10** and renaming some of the packages. But I seem to have the *-s1 packages installed already, hence the problem might be somewhere else? Anyway, I am not skilled or persistent enough to dig deeper into this kind of stuff (tracking renamed packages) on my own.

I have no idea what the real problem is. Maybe there are many reasons or the complexity depends on which packages one has installed in their system. I have lost any hope and the only solution I see is to format the system partition and install a fresh bullseye or wait until it becomes stable and hope the devs will fix the issue by then. Unless somebody here helps me, **please**. :)

Maybe this will help you find the solution:

```
# dpkg -l gcc-* libc*dev libgcc*
ii  gcc-10-base:amd64    10.2.1-1     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-10-base:i386     10.2.1-1     i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
un  gcc-4.3              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-4.4              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-4.5              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-4.6              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  gcc-8-base:amd64     8.3.0-6      amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-9                9.3.0-19     amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-9-base:amd64     9.3.0-19     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
un  gcc-9-doc            <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-9-locales        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-9-multilib       <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-doc              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-multilib         <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  gcc-10-base:amd64   10.2.1-1     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-10-base:i386    10.2.1-1     i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-8-base:amd64    8.3.0-6      amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-9-base:amd64    9.3.0-19     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
un  libc-dev            <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc0.1-dev         <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc0.3-dev         <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libc6-dev:amd64     2.28-10      amd64        GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
un  libc6.1-dev         <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libcurl4-gnutls-dev <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libgcc-9-dev:amd64  9.3.0-19     amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc-s1:amd64     10.2.1-1     amd64        GCC support library
ii  libgcc-s1:i386      10.2.1-1     i386         GCC support library
un  libgcc1             <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libgccjit-9-dev     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

EDIT (October 31, 2021)

Bullseye has been released as stable version, but I still cannot upgrade to it. During the last year I haven't really tried to solve it, but running `apt-get upgrade` from time to time allowed me to upgrade some (few) packages, probably those unaffected by the issue.

Here is the updated list of currently installed gcc-related packages:

```
ii  gcc-10-base:amd64    10.2.1-6     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-10-base:i386     10.2.1-6     i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
un  gcc-4.3              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-4.4              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-4.5              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-4.6              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  gcc-8-base:amd64     8.3.0-6      amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-9                9.3.0-22     amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-9-base:amd64     9.3.0-22     amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
un  gcc-9-doc            <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-9-locales        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-9-multilib       <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-doc              <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-multilib         <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc-dev             <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc0.1-dev          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc0.3-dev          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libc6-dev:amd64      2.28-10      amd64        GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
un  libc6.1-dev          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libcurl4-gnutls-dev  <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libgcc-9-dev:amd64   9.3.0-22     amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc-s1:amd64      10.2.1-6     amd64        GCC support library
ii  libgcc-s1:i386       10.2.1-6     i386         GCC support library
ii  libgcc1:amd64        1:10.1.0+rp2 amd64        GCC support library (transitional package)
un  libgccjit-9-dev      <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

And the output of dist-upgrade attempt:

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information..
Calculating update...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cracklib-runtime enchant fonts-dejavu fonts-linuxlibertine fonts-sil-gentium
  fonts-sil-gentium-basic freepats g++-9 gstreamer1.0-alsa
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio icoutils kate-data kde-runtime-data
  kde-style-qtcurve-qt5 kdelibs5-data libbctoolbox1 libboost-atomic1.67.0
  libboost-chrono1.67.0 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0
  libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0
  libboost-thread1.67.0 libbrlapi0.6 libbsh-java libbzrtp0 libcfitsio7
  libcrack2 libcroco3 libdlrestrictions1 libdouble-conversion1 libdrm-dev
  libegl-nvidia-legacy-390xx0:i386 libegl-nvidia0:i386 libegl1-nvidia
  libegl1-nvidia-legacy-390xx:i386 libenchant1c2a libevent-2.1-6 libexiv2-14
  libfaac0 libffi6:i386 libflite1 libfluidsynth1 libgadu3 libgit2-27
  libgles-nvidia-legacy-390xx1:i386 libgles-nvidia-legacy-390xx2:i386
  libgles-nvidia1 libgles-nvidia1:i386 libgles-nvidia2 libgles-nvidia2:i386
  libgles2-mesa-dev libglvnd-core-dev libglx-nvidia-legacy-390xx0:i386
  libglx-nvidia0 libglx-nvidia0:i386 libgpgme++2v5 libgps23
  libgrantlee-textdocument5 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgssdp-1.0-3 libgssdp-1.2-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-1.2-0
  libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libhogweed5 libhogweed5:i386 libhttp-parser2.8
  libice6:i386 libicu63 libicu63:i386 libigdgmm5 libigdgmm5:i386 libilmbase23
  libisl22 libjim0.77 libjson-c4 libjsoncpp1 libkaccounts1
  libkdecorations2private6 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data
  libkf5emoticons5 libkf5jsembed-data libkf5jsembed5 libkf5libkdepimakonadi5
  libkf5xmlrpcclient-data libkf5xmlrpcclient5 libkwineffects11
  libkwinglutils11 libkwinxrenderutils11 liblept5 liblilv-0-0 libllvm7
  libllvm7:i386 liblouis17 liblouisutdml8 liblrdf0 libmeanwhile1
  libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmpdec2 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0
  libmypaint-1.3-0 libnettle7 libnettle7:i386 libnice10 libntrack0
  libnvidia-eglcore:i386 libnvidia-glcore:i386 libnvidia-glvkspirv
  libnvidia-glvkspirv:i386 libnvidia-legacy-390xx-cfg1:i386
  libnvidia-legacy-390xx-eglcore:i386 libnvidia-legacy-390xx-glcore:i386
  libofa0 libokular5core8 libopenexr23 liborcus-0.14-0 libotr5 libperl5.28
  libplymouth4 libpoppler82 libpotrace0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython3.7 libpython3.7-minimal
  libpython3.7-stdlib libqhull7 libqpdf21 libqtcurve-utils2 libraw19 libre2-5
  libreadline5 libreadline7 libreoffice libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
  libreoffice-kde5 libreoffice-librelogo libreoffice-nlpsolver
  libreoffice-script-provider-bsh libreoffice-script-provider-js
  libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-wiki-publisher librubberband2
  libruby2.5 libsane libsbc1 libserd-0-0 libsisu-guice-java libsisu-ioc-java
  libsm6:i386 libsnmp30 libsord-0-0 libsoundtouch1 libspandsp2 libsratom-0-0
  libsrtp2-1 libssh-gcrypt-4 libstdc++-9-dev libtesseract4 libtexlua52
  libtidy5deb1 libtss2-udev libturbojpeg0 libu2f-udev libusbmuxd4 libutempter0
  libvidstab1.1 libvo-aacenc0 libvpx5 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi2
  libx11-xcb-dev libx265-165 libxcb-dri2-0-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev
  libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev
  libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxdamage-dev
  libxshmfence-dev libxtst6:i386 libzbar0 libzimg2 mesa-common-dev
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 nvidia-driver-bin oxygen-icon-theme perl-modules-5.28
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common polkit-kde-1 printer-driver-hpijs python2
  python2-minimal python3-sip python3.7-minimal
  qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze qtcore4-l10n ruby-did-you-mean
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ffmpeg gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad kaccessible katepart kde-l10n-pl kde-runtime
  kde-style-breeze-qt4 kde-style-qtcurve-qt4 kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-plugins
  kdoctools kopete libattica0.4 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libdbusmenu-qt2
  libegl1-nvidia:i386 libgl1-nvidia-glx libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
  libgl1-nvidia-legacy-390xx-glx:i386 libgnustep-base1.26 libhfstospell10
  libkabc4 libkactivities6 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4
  libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4
  libkemoticons4 libkf5followupreminder5 libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5
  libkf5sendlater5 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4
  libkldap4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4
  libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpimidentities4
  libkpimkdav-data libkpimkdav5abi2 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkpty4
  libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libktexteditor4
  libldb1 libmediastreamer-base10 libmediastreamer-voip10 libnode64
  libntrack-qt4-1 libortp13 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-qt-1-1 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libpython-stdlib libqca2
  libqca2-plugins libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative
  libqt4-designer libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml
  libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4
  libreoffice-style-tango libsolid4 libtaskmanager6 libthreadweaver4
  libtss2-esys0 mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-server-core-10.3
  nvidia-driver nvidia-driver-libs-nonglvnd nvidia-driver-libs-nonglvnd:i386
  nvidia-driver-libs-nonglvnd-i386:i386
  nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver-libs-nonglvnd:i386
  nvidia-legacy-390xx-nonglvnd-vulkan-icd:i386 nvidia-nonglvnd-vulkan-common
  nvidia-nonglvnd-vulkan-icd nvidia-nonglvnd-vulkan-icd:i386 phonon
  phonon-backend-gstreamer plasma-scriptengine-javascript python
  python-minimal python-parted python-talloc python3.7 qdbus qt-at-spi ruby2.5
  sni-qt uno-libs3 user-manager
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf apt-config-icons-hidpi
  apt-config-icons-large-hidpi bup bup-doc cpp-10 dctrl-tools dvisvgm
  enchant-2 fonts-urw-base35 g++-10 gcc-10 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
  glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-x:i386 hwdata ibus-data isolinux
  kmailtransport-akonadi kontrast kpeople-vcard kup-backup kuserfeedback-doc
  libaa1:i386 libabsl20200923 libaom3 libasan6 libatopology2 libavc1394-0:i386
  libavif9 libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0
  libboost-locale1.74.0 libboost-regex1.74.0 libboost-thread1.74.0 libbpf0
  libbrlapi0.8 libbrotli-dev libbrotli1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libc-devtools
  libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcfitsio9 libclone-perl libcrypt-dev
  libcrypt1:i386 libcuda1 libcuda1:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libcurl4:i386
  libdatrie1:i386 libdav1d4 libdav1d5 libdebuginfod1 libdeflate0
  libdeflate0:i386 libdouble-conversion3 libdv4:i386 libdvdread8 libdw1:i386
  libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl-nvidia-tesla-450-0 libegl-nvidia-tesla-450-0:i386
  libegl1:i386 libenchant-2-2 libevent-2.1-7 libexiv2-27 libfaudio0
  libfaudio0:i386 libfontbox-java libfontconfig-dev libfreetype-dev
  libfribidi0:i386 libgav1-0 libgbm1:i386 libgcc-10-dev libgdbm-compat4:i386
  libgdbm6:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386
  libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgit2-1.1 libgl1-nvidia-tesla-450-glvnd-glx
  libgl1-nvidia-tesla-450-glvnd-glx:i386 libgles-nvidia-tesla-450-1
  libgles-nvidia-tesla-450-1:i386 libgles-nvidia-tesla-450-2
  libgles-nvidia-tesla-450-2:i386 libglx-nvidia-tesla-450-0
  libglx-nvidia-tesla-450-0:i386 libgnustep-base1.27 libgps28
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsettings-qt1 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgudev-1.0-0:i386 libgupnp-1.2-0
  libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhfstospell11 libhogweed6:i386 libhttp-parser2.9
  libicu67 libicu67:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libigdgmm11
  libigdgmm11:i386 libilbc3 libilmbase25 libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libjim0.79
  libjs-highlight.js libjson-c5 libjuh-java libjurt-java libkaccounts2
  libkcolorpicker0 libkdecorations2private7 libkdsoap1 libkf5authcore5
  libkf5dav-data libkf5dav5 libkf5kdegames7 libkf5pulseaudioqt2
  libkimageannotator-common libkimageannotator0 libkpmcore10 libksgrd9
  libksignalplotter9 libksysguardformatter1 libksysguardsensorfaces1
  libksysguardsensors1 libkuserfeedbackcore1 libkuserfeedbackwidgets1
  libkwaylandserver5 libkwineffects12a libkwinglutils12 libkwinxrenderutils12
  libldb2 liblibreoffice-java libllvm11 libllvm11:i386 liblouis20
  liblouisutdml9 libmarkdown2 libmd0 libmd0:i386 libmd4c0 libmpdec3
  libmypaint-1.5-1 libncursesw6:i386 libnettle8:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386
  libnode72 libnotificationmanager1 libnsl-dev libnsl2 libnsl2:i386
  libnspr4:i386 libnss-nis libnss-nis:i386 libnss-nisplus libnss-nisplus:i386
  libnss3:i386 libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1 libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1:i386
  libnvidia-tesla-450-cbl libnvidia-tesla-450-cfg1 libnvidia-tesla-450-cuda1
  libnvidia-tesla-450-cuda1:i386 libnvidia-tesla-450-eglcore
  libnvidia-tesla-450-eglcore:i386 libnvidia-tesla-450-encode1
  libnvidia-tesla-450-encode1:i386 libnvidia-tesla-450-glcore
  libnvidia-tesla-450-glcore:i386 libnvidia-tesla-450-glvkspirv
  libnvidia-tesla-450-glvkspirv:i386 libnvidia-tesla-450-ml1
  libnvidia-tesla-450-nvcuvid1 libnvidia-tesla-450-nvcuvid1:i386
  libnvidia-tesla-450-ptxjitcompiler1 libnvidia-tesla-450-ptxjitcompiler1:i386
  libnvidia-tesla-450-rtcore libokular5core9 libopenexr25 libopengl0:i386
  liborcus-0.16-0 liborcus-parser-0.16-0 libpango-1.0-0:i386
  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpci3:i386 libpdfbox-java
  libperl5.32 libperl5.32:i386 libphonenumber8 libphonon4qt5-data
  libpipewire-0.3-0 libpipewire-0.3-modules libplymouth5 libpoppler-cpp0v5
  libpoppler-glib8:i386 libpoppler102 libpoppler102:i386 libprimus-vk1
  libprimus-vk1:i386 libprocesscore9 libprocessui9 libprocps8 libprotobuf23
  libproxy1v5:i386 libpsl5:i386 libpython3.9 libpython3.9-minimal
  libpython3.9-stdlib libqhull-r8.0 libqpdf28 libqrcodegencpp1
  libqt5networkauth5 libqt5qmlmodels5 libqt5qmlworkerscript5
  libqt5quickparticles5 libqt5virtualkeyboard5 libraw1394-11:i386 libraw20
  libre2-9 libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-plasma libreoffice-qt5
  libreoffice-sdbc-mysql libridl-java librtmp1:i386 libruby2.7 libsane1
  libsane1:i386 libshout3:i386 libsidplay1v5 libslang2:i386 libsnmp40
  libsnmp40:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libsource-highlight-common
  libsource-highlight4v5 libspa-0.2-modules libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh2-1:i386
  libstb0 libstb0:i386 libstdc++-10-dev libtag1v5:i386 libtag1v5-vanilla:i386
  libtaskmanager6abi1 libthai0:i386 libtirpc-common libtirpc-dev libtirpc3
  libtirpc3:i386 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-sys1
  libtss2-tcti-cmd0 libtss2-tcti-device0 libtss2-tcti-mssim0
  libtss2-tcti-swtpm0 libtwolame0:i386 libudfread0 libuno-cppu3
  libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3
  libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoil-java libunoloader-java libunwind8:i386
  libusbmuxd6 libvmaf1 libvorbisidec1:i386 libwavpack1:i386
  libwayland-server0:i386 libx264-164 libx265-192 libxcb-res0 libxcb-util1
  libxcb-xinput0 libxstring-perl libxv1:i386 libz3-4 libz3-4:i386
  libzxingcore1 linux-compiler-gcc-10-x86 linux-headers-5.10.0-9-amd64
  linux-headers-5.10.0-9-common linux-image-5.10.0-9-amd64 linux-kbuild-5.10
  mailcap mariadb-client-core-10.5 mariadb-server-core-10.5 media-types
  nvidia-egl-common nvidia-settings-tesla-450 nvidia-smi
  nvidia-tesla-450-alternative nvidia-tesla-450-driver
  nvidia-tesla-450-driver-bin nvidia-tesla-450-driver-libs
  nvidia-tesla-450-driver-libs:i386 nvidia-tesla-450-egl-icd
  nvidia-tesla-450-egl-icd:i386 nvidia-tesla-450-kernel-dkms
  nvidia-tesla-450-kernel-support nvidia-tesla-450-smi
  nvidia-tesla-450-vdpau-driver nvidia-tesla-450-vulkan-icd
  nvidia-tesla-450-vulkan-icd:i386 nvidia-vulkan-common par2 partitionmanager
  pci.ids perl-modules-5.32 perl-tk pipewire pipewire-bin plasma-disks
  plasma-workspace-data primus-libs:i386 printer-driver-indexbraille
  printer-driver-oki psmisc pulseaudio-module-gsettings python3-distro
  python3-fuse python3-ldb python3-mutagen python3-parted python3-pycryptodome
  python3-pylibacl python3-pyqt5.sip python3-pyxattr python3-talloc
  python3-tornado python3-websockets python3.9 python3.9-minimal
  qml-module-gsettings1.0 qml-module-org-kde-kitemmodels
  qml-module-org-kde-ksysguard qml-module-org-kde-people
  qml-module-org-kde-prison qml-module-org-kde-quickcharts
  qml-module-org-kde-userfeedback qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qtqml
  qml-module-qtquick-particles2 qml-module-qtwebengine qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5
  qtspeech5-speechd-plugin rtmpdump ruby-rubygems ruby2.7 smartmontools
  systemd-timesyncd texlive-luatex tpm-udev uno-libs-private xkbset
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-tesla-450 xsettingsd yt-dlp
The following packages have been kept back:
  gstreamer1.0-libav libasound2-plugins libasound2-plugins:i386 libavcodec58
  libavcodec58:i386 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavresample4:i386
  libavutil56 libavutil56:i386 libchromaprint1 libk3b7-extracodecs libmfx1
  libpostproc55 libswresample3 libswresample3:i386 libswscale5 vlc-data
  vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-video-output
The following packages will be upgraded:
**(removed this list due to character limit)**
1046 upgraded, 376 newly installed, 126 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 1 676 MB archives.
After this operation, 1 383 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: I have added Ryan Pavlik's repositories, but it didn't really change anything.
running _# apt-get upgrade_ let me to upgrade 4 packages: _login_, _passwd_, _util-linux_ and _util_linux_locales_, but _# apt-get dist-upgrade_ still wants to delete about 100 packages which I don't want to delete.

Comment: The upgrade from Debian 10 to 11 was fixed before the release, Ryan Pavlik’s repositories are no longer necessary. You might be running into package removals related to the Python 2 cleanup...

Comment: Fixed or not, I am stuck basically at the same point as last year...

Comment: With the same `gcc-10` problem?

Comment: With the same `gcc-10`, `gcc-8` or whatever package problem, yes.

I have edited the original post as you requested.

Comment: Thanks. That list of removals seems OK to me, which packages do you want to keep? I don’t see any `gcc-8` or `gcc-10` problems here.

Comment: 1) I am not sure what every single of the _to be removed_ packages is responsible for, but I certainly would like to keep the KDE-related packages (KDE is my window manager, I feel like removing these would result in a crash), the removal of nvidia-related packages is worrying me too. I would like to keep ffmpeg as well.

Answer (score 0):

All your GCC-related issues appear to have been resolved.

The packages that are listed as being removed are mostly unsurprising:

- obsolete KDE components (`kaccessible`, `katepart`, `kde-l10n-pl`, `kde-runtime` etc. were all removed from Debian 11),
- obsolete libraries,
- obsolete Python 2-related packages (see [Debian 'bullseye' - 'apt full-upgrade' removes whole lot of packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609572/86440) for relevant links).

That leaves `ffmpeg`, the `gstreamer` plugins, and most importantly for you I imagine, the NVIDIA drivers. The former are probably related to whatever is holding back the VLC upgrade. The latter appears to be related to the switch to Tesla drivers, but I don’t know what would cause that.

To make progress, you could try forcing partial upgrades of troublesome packages:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
sudo apt install nvidia-driver
```

At best this will work as-is, and upgrade the corresponding package sets; at worst, it should give you some more clues as to what exactly is going wrong.